# Spring Application's build file cannot execute by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, gradle

### what happend and What I want to do

I made a Springboot Project with spring initializr (https://start.spring.io/).

But I cannot executed built jar file with this error.

```
 java -jar build/libs/spring302-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
        at com.kaede.spring302.Spring302ApplicationKt.main(Spring302Application.kt)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        ... 1 more
```

What should I do ?

I want to do this because I need to build to Docker Container.

### How I made this project

I selected

- Kotlin
- Gradle 7.2
- Spring 3.0.2
- Java 17

And I used IntelliJ to build.

Project Name is spring302
NameSpace is com.kaede

### 1. Tried to Add Manifest Main-Class

```
java -jar build/libs/kotlin1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar

Error: Could not find or load main class
```

First, I tried to just build, then happend this error.

```
tasks.withType<Jar> {
    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.kaede.spring302.Spring302Application"
    }
}
```

So I added Manifest Main-Class in spring302/build.gradle.kts

```
java -jar build/libs/spring302-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar
Error: Main method not found in class com.kaede.spring302.Spring302Application, 
please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
```

Then I got it is not Java Main Method Error.

### 2. Changed Main-Class to classNameKt

I changed Main-Class from Spring302Application to Spring302ApplicationKt

I heard Kotlin class will change classNameKt.java.

```
tasks.withType<Jar> {
    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.kaede.spring302.Spring302ApplicationKt"
    }
}
```

So I changed my Main-Class .

```
java -jar build/libs/spring302-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
        at com.kaede.spring302.Spring302ApplicationKt.main(Spring302Application.kt)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        ... 1 more
```

Then I got NoClassDefFoundError in Spring302ApplicationKt.main.

```
javap spring302-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain/com/kaede/spring302/Spring302ApplicationKt.class 
Compiled from "Spring302Application.kt"
public final class com.kaede.spring302.Spring302ApplicationKt {
  public static final void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

Even my output has main.

### 3. Removed .m2/repository and rebuild

```
 rm -rf ~/.m2/repository
```

I thought dependencies are complicated, So I removed all and re-build.

But things did not change.

### what I expect

I can execute jar file

### 4. Changed Main Method from runApplication to SpringApplication.run

In main

```
runApplication<Spring302Application>(*args)
```

to

```
SpringApplication.run(Spring302Application::class.java, *args
```

But NoClassDefFoundError does not change

### build.gradle.kts

This is my full dependencies.

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.0.2"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.0"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.22"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.7.22"
}

group = "com.kaede"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
tasks.withType<Jar> {
    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.kaede.spring302.Spring302ApplicationKt"
    }

}
```

Comment: springboot plugin generates two jars,  an executable and a plain jar. maybe you just try to execute the wrong one ?  try `java -jar build/libs/spring302-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: No, my springboot generates just **plain** one.
`ls build/libs/` ->  `spring302-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar`

Comment: Sorry, ` ./gradlew build` out put not plain one.
But cannot found main class too. `java -jar build/libs/spring302-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` ->      
`Error: Could not find or load main class com.kaede.spring302.Spring302ApplicationKt`p

Comment: what task did you use to generate this "-plain" jar ?  Spring boot gradle plugin provides a `bootJar` task used to generate the executable (fatjar) jar .  `jar` task on the other hand, will produce the "plain" jar . see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging-executable.and-plain-archives .  if you execute the lifecycle task "build" you should get both jar & bootJar jars

Comment: you need to remove the ` attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.kaede.spring302.Spring302ApplicationKt"`  from your build file, let Springboot plugin detect the class automatically itself

Comment: @M.Ricciuti Thank you sooooo much! 
Problem solved!

I removed `tasks.withType<Jar> {
 manifest {
  attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.kaede.spring302.Spring302ApplicationKt"
 }
}`

And execute `./gradlew bulild` 
After that I execute `java -jar build/libs/spring302-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` 
Then, `Started Spring302ApplicationKt in 5.47 seconds`

Comment: I should build Spring gradle project by `./gradlew buiild` . NOT by IntelliJ's build button. Because IntelliJ's build button outputs `plain` one only.

Answer (score 0):

check your spring boot project build gradle configuration file if you have something like this:

```
application {
   mainClass.set("MainKt")
}
```

remove it and build your project again